# How to combine multiple succeeding rows in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata, data-manipulation

I have a dataset, for example

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell A1 | Cell B1 | Cell C1 | Cell D1 |
| Cell A2 | Cell B2 | Cell C2 | Cell D2 |
| Cell A3 | Cell B3 | Cell C3 | Cell D3 |
| Cell A4 | Cell B4 | Cell C4 | Cell D4 |

Is there a possibility that I can join n rows together. For example, row 1 and row 2 get joined together, while mainting the columns?
So, I can get

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell A1, A2 | Cell B1, B2 | Cell C1, C2 | Cell D1, D2 |
| Cell A3, A4 | Cell B3, B4 | Cell C3, C4 | Cell D3, D4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with `row_number(), monotonically_increasing_id()`.

Create the groups by getting `%` on the `row_number` field then use `sum` window operation to get groups.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
window = Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy('Column A')
window_mid = Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy('mid')

df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(window)).\
  withColumn("grp", (col("rn")%2)).\
    withColumn("mid", monotonically_increasing_id()).\
    withColumn("sum", sum(col("grp")).over(window_mid)).\
        groupBy("sum").agg(array_join(collect_list(col("Column A")),',').alias("column a"),
                           array_join(collect_list(col("Column B")),',').alias("column b"),
                           array_join(collect_list(col("Column C")),',').alias("column c"),
                           array_join(collect_list(col("Column D")),',').alias("column d")).\
          drop(*['rn','grp','mid','sum']).show()

#+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
#|       column a|       column b|       column c|       column d|
#+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
#|Cell A1,Cell A2|Cell B1,Cell B2|Cell C1,Cell C2|Cell D1,Cell D2|
#|Cell A3,Cell A4|Cell B3,Cell B4|Cell C3,Cell C4|Cell D3,Cell D4|
#+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define some grouping column that indicates that rows 1 and 2 are in a group, rows 3 and 4 are in a group, etc.. Once you do that (I do below by getting row_number, dividing by 2, and rounding), you can use `groupby()` along with `agg(collect_list())`, as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

(
    df
    .withColumn("row",F.round(F.row_number().over(Window().orderBy(F.lit("a")))/2))
    .groupby("row")
    .agg(*[F.array_join(F.collect_list("Col" + l),",").alias("Col" + l) for l in ['A','B','C','D']])
    .drop("row")
    .show()
)
```

Output

```
| ColA| ColB| ColC| ColD|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|A1,A2|B1,B2|C1,C2|D1,D2|
|A3,A4|B3,B4|C3,C4|D3,D4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Input (`sp` is a SparkSession object):

```
df = sp.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame({
        "ColA": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"],
        "ColB": ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"],
        "ColC": ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"],
        "ColD": ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"],
    })
)
```